# I need an expression or a different group of words for "long list of reasons I am unworthy/ a failure

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm looking for another way to say: I couldn't help but ponder the long list of reasons I am unworthy/ a failure.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Writing advice is off topic here. You might try Writers.SE, but read their FAQ before you post there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could say something like:
I couldn't help but ponder the *litany* of my failings.

[*Litany* has definitions of:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litany)

> a usually lengthy recitation or enumeration *a familiar litany of complaints*
>
> a sizable series or set *a litany of problems*

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines, catalog and host would also work. "I worked through the catalog of my failings", or "My life consists of a host of failures"

Answer (score 0):

OP might reflect upon his [multifarious shortcomings](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22was%20buff%20naked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22multifarious%20shortcomings%22&oq=%22multifarious%20shortcomings%22&gs_l=serp.3...1697409.1706383.2.1706783.39.39.0.0.0.3.198.3147.32j7.39.0...0.0...1c.1.B-bAW8rON3M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1254&bih=886).

Comment: I love both ideas!